# How to fix error in docker container with finding yarn?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I am trying to set up the 0x Launch Kit Frontend (https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-frontend). I have built it into a docker container with the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-frontend/blob/development/Dockerfile. When trying to do the command `docker run image:name yarn build` which should run the container from the local Docker image, I get the error `docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 32: yarn: not found` . Why is this and how can I fix it? It seems that yarn is installed in the Dockerfile (linked above) in this part:

```
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade && \
apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies bash git openssh python make g++ && \
yarn --no-cache || \
apk del build-dependencies && \
yarn cache clean
```

Also, here is the code for the docker-entrypoint.sh file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    # vim:sw=4:ts=4:et
    set -e
    if [ "$1" = "nginx" -o "$1" = "nginx-debug" ]; then
         if /usr/bin/find "/docker-entrypoint.d/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print - 
           quit 2>/dev/null | read v; then
          echo "$0: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration"
          echo "$0: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/"
          find "/docker-entrypoint.d/" -follow -type f -print | sort -n | while read -r f; do
              case "$f" in
                   *.sh)
                   if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                       echo "$0: Launching $f";
                       "$f"
                   else
                       # warn on shell scripts without exec bit
                       echo "$0: Ignoring $f, not executable";
                   fi
                   ;;
               *) echo "$0: Ignoring $f";;
            esac
         done
    echo "$0: Configuration complete; ready for start up"
    else
        echo "$0: No files found in /docker-entrypoint.d/, skipping configuration"
    fi
    fi
    exec "$@"
```

Comment: Which is you current Dockerfile? as the one mentioned does not have entrypoint?

Comment: My Dockerfile is exactly the same as the one from the github (https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-frontend/blob/development/Dockerfile). I believe the docker-entrypoint.sh is some standard file that is called even if I don't have an ENTRYPOINT command in the Dockerfile.